# GET request from a local server not working

Tags: javascript, express, get, axios

I am trying to obtain json files with axios' GET request, but the information is not retrieved.

In `index.js` (retrieving information):

```
axios.get('http://localhost:1000/getpost/')
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

Backend endpoint `getpost.js` (sending information):

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var Posts = require('../models/post-model.js');

router.route('/').get(() => {
    Posts.find({color: "Green"})
        .then((res) => {
            return res;
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

I have also tried `return Posts.find({color: "Green"});` inside the `router.route('/').get...` function, 
but the value returned is different compared to the one in the promise which is the one I need. I checked that the information is actually sent with `console.log(res)`, but it is not received in the frontend--when I log the result there, it is null.

Comment: Can you see if the results are coming in postman when you do the get request, It would be better if you could show your index.js with how you are mapping the route

Comment: Great note! I used insomnia (similar to postman) to test the GET request and it does not return (does not stop loading)

Comment: well, i probably think that you are mapping the route incorrectly...post your index.js

Comment: There is nothing in `index.js` that relates to the GET request besides what I've included, and the url is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I was not passing the result properly.

The `router` in `getpost.js` should be:

```
router.route('/').get((req, res) => { 
    Posts.find({color: "Green"})
       .then((posts) => res.json(posts));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not doing anything with the route response. Maybe something like...

```
router.route('/').get((req, res1) => {
    Posts.find({color: "Green"})
        .then((res) => {
            res1.end(res);
        });
});
```

(assuming `res` is the data in plaint text, if it is a JavaScript object you'll do `res1.json(res)` or `res1.jsonp(res)`)

Comment: I did `console.log(res)` and I got the json, when I do it over the receiving end in `index.js` I get nothing.

Comment: Your answer seems right, I tried something similar and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to map the route to getpost as:

```
router.route('/getpost')
```

So your getpost would be as:

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var Posts = require('../models/post-model.js');

router.route('/getpost').get(() => {
    Posts.find({color: "Green"})
        .then((res) => {
            res.send({status:200,message:res});
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: That's not true, because I am mapping to the url which I already provide `http://localhost:1000/getpost/` so it would be erroneous to include `/getpost`--and I did receive an error this way

Comment: @David, you have the mapping in index.js or app.js that you have used for your api, just show the part for the getpost

Comment: That was not the issue, I resolved it by changing to the code in my answer